# VBA For Loop STUCK

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, insert

I have a For loop that is running through all rows (it also merges the inserted rows) ... The road block I am running into is while going through the rows I am inserting rows which is throwing it off.

Example:

Adding 5 rows after A and instead of going to B it goes to one of the added rows under A.

Initial Look

- A
- B
- C
- D

First Pass adds 5 blank rows under A.

Second pass keeps adding more space after A instead of jumping down to B.

```
For Each x In wksProd.Range("A3", "A" & iRow)
If x <> "0" Then
    Rows(x.Row).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(5).Insert
    With Range(x.Address, ConvertToLetter(x.Column) & x.Row + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With Range(ConvertToLetter(x.Column + 1) & x.Row, ConvertToLetter(x.Column + 1) & x.Row + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    <-- some other formatting code here -->
End If
Next x
```

Comment: Can you try `For Each x In wksProd.Range("A3:A" & iRow)` on the first line?

Comment: Still same result.  When its going back to x it is not taking into consideration that the +5 rows were non-existent when the loop started.

Comment: Just to make it clear. You want to add five rows under each of those letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping on worksheet `wksProd`, but working against whatever worksheet happens to be the `ActiveSheet`.

I've highlighted the implicit references to the active sheet with `*stars*`:

```
For Each x In wksProd.Range("A3", "A" & iRow)
If x <> "0" Then
    *Rows*(x.Row).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(5).Insert
    With *Range*(x.Address, ConvertToLetter(x.Column) & x.Row + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With *Range*(ConvertToLetter(x.Column + 1) & x.Row, ConvertToLetter(x.Column + 1) & x.Row + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    <-- some other formatting code here -->
End If
Next x
```

And you probably have more. Make sure you're working with `wksProd` - it may or may not be the active sheet. If it isn't, then you're inserting rows in the wrong worksheet. If it is, then you're **modifying a collection as you're iterating it** - and that's never a good idea.

> ```
> Rows(x.Row).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(5).Insert
> ```

Comment: I put wksProd in front of each of those that you mentioned.  Still have the same issue.  It goes to cell A3 and inserts 5 rows after A3.  When it hits the loop to x to go to next x it is going to A4 (instead of A3 + 5) how can I increment x in a for each loop?

Comment: @c3nixon that's the "modifying a collection as you're iterating it" part screwing you over. You can't change how a `For Each` loop iterates an object collection, so you need to change your control flow - e.g. using a `For` loop with `Step 5` specified, but then know that iterating an object collection with a `For` loop is going to slow down the code.

Comment: Ahh... so I completely misunderstood your statement... Got it working now!   Ill post as answer -- Thanks for the help Mat!

Answer (score 0):

Thx Mat's Mug -- this resolved it (using For with Step vs For Each.

```
    For x = 3 To ((iRow + 2) * 5) Step 6
    wksProd.Rows(x).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(5).Insert
    With wksProd.Range("A" & x, "A" & x + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With wksProd.Range("B" & x, "B" & x + 5)
        .Merge
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    <-- some other formatting code here -->
Next x
```